# Finding the side trip

Tags: testing, graph

The following question is from Introduction to Software Testing by Paul Ammann and Jeff Offutt.

> Consider the simple path [3, 2, 4, 5, 6] and test path [1, 2, 3, 2, 4,
>   6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7]. Does the test path tour the simple path
>   directly? With a side trip? If so, write down the side trip.

Can someone explain to me how to get the answer, please?

Comment: You do realize that many of us don't have that book, right?  And you haven't provided enough information in your question to make it answerable without reading the book.  Voting to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The desired path is to visit nodes 3, 2, 4, 5, then 6 in that order.

In your test path, you eventually visit nodes 3,2,4 -- then you take a side trip and visit nodes 6, 1, 2 before returning to node 4.  You then complete the desired path by visiting nodes 5 and 6.

It might be easier to visualize by drawing 7 nodes at random and drawing the path(s) taken.